# My Class Method is not Calling from assembly in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following Code structure. I want Calling Method from DLL/Assembly. I have tried to result with:

```
string strDLL = "Dll Path";

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(strDLL);
Type type = assembly.GetType("NameSpace.ClassName");
object objplugin = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var objUserid = objplugin.GetType().GetProperty("UserID"); 
objUserid.SetValue(objplugin,this.txtUserName.Text, null);                     
//objplugin.UserID = this.txtUserName.Text;
//objplugin.Password = this.txtPassword.Text;         
var connection1 =objplugin.GetType().GetMethod("MethodName",null);
```

But I am not able to calling Method From Assembly.:

Comment: `But I am not able to calling Method From Aassembly.` you need to do better than this, have you stepped through your code, are any of the results returning null? Secondly why don't you just add the DLL as a project reference and be done with it

Comment: But i want add assembly by Command prompt.

Comment: @RamkrishnaJadhav do you want to call a method of assembly or call method of your class staying in assembly. and  "But I am not able to calling Method From Assembly.:" what problem are you facing ? compile time error or null value ?

Comment: Null value.....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you.

```
string strDLL = @"Dll Path";
string txtUserName = "test user name";

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(strDLL);
Type type = assembly.GetType("TestLib.MyClass");
object objplugin = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var objUserIdProp = type.GetProperty("UserID");
objUserIdProp.SetValue(objplugin, txtUserName);
var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("TestMethod");
methodInfo.Invoke(objplugin, null);

namespace TestLib
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public void TestMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestMethod work");
        }
    }
}
```